# Telerik Kendo UI Grid Column Headers Extra Line on Top

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid whose header adds an extra blank line above the grid and I would really like to get rid of it. See the image below:[image: Telerik Kendo UI Grid with extra line on top]

The following settings are set for the grid:

```
filterable: true,
sortable: true,
resizable: true,
```

The following CSS has been added to get the column headers text to wrap, according to documentation:

```
.k-grid .k-grid-header .k-header .k-link { height: auto; }
.k-grid .k-grid-header .k-header { white-space: normal; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once. Adding **vertical-align** attribute for the columns header solved it for me.

```
headerAttributes: { style: "text-align:center; vertical-align:top;" }
```

You can try this and see if it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exact same issue. Adding this to my css file fixed the issue.

```
.k-grid-header 
{
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.k-grid .k-grid-header .k-header .k-link {
    height: auto;
}

.k-grid .k-grid-header .k-header {
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #cce0ff;
}

.k-header .k-link {
    text-align: center;
}
```